# Add an entry for Ubuntu on Windows 8 boot loader

Tags: 12.10, boot, dual-boot, bootloader, windows-8

I have installed Ubuntu 12.10 by creating free space in Windows 8 and then using that space to create 3 partitions, one for SWAP, one for GRUB (mounting point is /boot) and one for the actual OS. I did this so the Windows 8 boot loader wouldn't be overwritten in case I ever wanted to remove Ubuntu. I can still boot into Ubuntu if I select the boot loader from the BIOS.

I want to add Ubuntu to the Windows 8 boot loader and I've been told to use EasyBCD. The issue with that is it doesn't actually direct Windows to the GRUB file, but rather to something like `autogrub0.mri`. I have found another programme called Visual BCD which will allow me to actually set the bootloader paths and drives.

From here, I don't quite know what to do. I believe I have it set to the correct drive but I don't know if I'm directing to the  right file. I think it's `/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/grub.efi`. I don't know if that's the right file, if I need to remove `/boot` or if the `/` need to be `\` as that's what Windows uses.

Sorry for such a lengthy post, please help!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using UEFI and Secure Boot?  I'm going to assume you are since you are picking a UEFI file.  I also would recommend disabling secure boot while you at least try to get it to work.  Re-enable it when done and re-test.

I'm assuming you are running a 64 bit Windows 8, and therefore must use a 64-bit Boot Loader per the UEFI standard, and then you must be running 64-Bit version of Ubuntu.  If you are not, then you have to disable UEFI.  I would recommend just re-installing with the 64 bit version.

To answer your question:

If you are using 64 bit Ubuntu the file I believe you should use would be located in

`/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi`

If you are using secure boot I think you will need to launch this file since it's signed:

`/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi`

If you are using 32-bit Ubuntu you must disable UEFI

So, here is a link about EasyBCD, looks like you must need 2.2 to have EFI support

https://neosmart.net/forums/showthread.php?t=9342

You would probably want to look for threads about GRUB using the last loaded and set it to zero time if you are using Windows the boot loader so you never see it if you pick Ubuntu.

I'm going to agree with the other answer, I highly recommend running GRUB as your boot loader.  It works great, it detects the Windows .efi files and launches them (Not in secure boot though this is bug [#1091464](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2/+bug/1091464)).  I would be surprised if EasyBCD allows you to boot all OS's in SecureBoot.  I use Grub Customizer to delete unneeded entries, give it a background, and reduce the timer.  It's just far more customizable and has a lot of support and history.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you have figured something else out by now.

But just wanted to suggest that you not use the windows boot-loader, as it is incredibly fickle when it comes to recognizing Linux partitions. I've had it working fine, then had it go missing again after windows updated and I've also had it keep Ubuntu listed, but fail to actually boot to it both after upgrading Ubuntu versions and reinstalling Ubuntu.

Instead, it is very easy to use Grub, and if you ever decide that Ubuntu is not for you (which will hopefully never come up), you can use a 'secure remix' liveCD/USB to uninstall Ubuntu and run Boot Repair so that it loads directly into windows as it normally would. I've heard people say that they don't like Grub, but in my experience it rarely has troubles recognizing any other OS and when it does it is easy to fix by simply running Boot Repair, which has a great support system to help you should you encounter anything you can't resolve. (I don't imagine Microsoft is overly keen on helping you get your Ubuntu partition running, hence why you are asking here, not there.)

Again, hopefully you have figured something out, but I just wanted to make you, and anyone else who might have the same problem, aware that you will have a much harder time getting the windows boot-loader to work and will surely have more troubles with it in the end.

Answer (score 0):

> if you ever decide that Ubuntu is not for you (which will hopefully never come up), you can use a 'secure remix' liveCD/USB to uninstall Ubuntu and run Boot Repair so that it loads directly into windows as it normally would.

Interestingly on my Lenovo U410 I don't have to do any of that - Ubuntu is listed in the Boot section of the BIOS setup; all I do is delete it there and the Windows bootloader returns to normal.